# Bash Script: subl command won't open file when script run from git bash terminal, runs successfully from windows cmd

Tags: bash, shell, sublimetext

### Problem

I'm trying to write a Bash Shell Script which populates a file with some basic header type information and then opens the file for editing in sublime. So far I have the script written and have been able to confirm that the code is behaving as expected until the very last line `subl $filename`

***UPDATE***: Further testing found that when the $filename variable points to a git repository the subl command fails when issued by script but when given a destination path anywhere else the script executes the subl command flawlessly. What is more puzzling is the invoking the subl command on a file pointing to a Git repo works fine in terminal???

### Verison and Where Results

---Git Bash: GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)

```
~ $ where bash
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
```

---Sublime : Sublime Text Build 3126

```
$ where subl
C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe
```

### Error

> line 31: /c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl: Bad address

### .sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#Set your blog site's post directory here
ppath=~/Desktop/blog-sites/CPSC350-rudiment-developerblog/_posts

# Get user input
echo "Post Title: "
read title
echo "Post Categories: "
read keyw

# Process Input
ptitle=${title// /-}                            # convert spaces in title to hyphens
plc=`echo "$ptitle" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`   # convert title to lowercase
pdate=`date +%Y-%m-%d`                             # create date as Year-Month-Date
filename=$ppath/$pdate-$plc.markdown                  # location to create the new file in YYYY-MM-DD-filename format
touch $filename                                     # create the new blank post

# Set post YML header data and push to post file
echo "---
layout: post
title: $title
date: $pdate -0400
categories: [$keyw]
---" > $filename

# Open file in sublime
subl $filename
```

## ~/.bash_profile

```
# Add directories to PATH variable
export PATH="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3:~/.scripts:$PATH:."
```

## Attempts

I've confirmed that each line when run in terminal outside the script executes without error. I've used both UNIX style and Windows style `$filename` paths, returning the same results. I've executed the subl command in cmd without error. Also I've tried using alias for subl, which only returned the same error. I've also tried to call subl.exe using its absolute path within the script; replacing line 31 with; 
`/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe` 
which returns the same Bad Address error.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE*** Just thought it would help to illustrate what I've been able to get working and what doesn't.

#### Doesn't work

When `subl` is called with the variable $filename=`~Desktop/blog-sites/CPSC350-rudiment-developerblog/some-name.markdown` # CPSC350... is a git repo

#### Works

When `subl` is called with the variable $filename=`~Desktop/blog-sites/some-name.markdown` # not in git repo

Comment: What happens if you instead use `cmd /c start subl` to invoke the editor?

Comment: And one more: If `subl` is a native Windows application, it might not like `$filename` to be expanded to a Unix-style path.

Comment: Issued the command `start subl` in cmd and it behaves as expected. As for the file paths, I forgot to mention that I did play around with that too. Also running the script line for line in the gitbash terminal works flawlessly, unix style path and all. I suspect this has something to do with the destination path being a git repository. As soon as I test the script with a path outside a repo, it executes the final subl $filename perfectly.

Comment: probably not the issue, but why don't you put quotes around `"$filename"` like this. In case there are spaces in filename

Comment: you also don't need to escape spaces if they are in `"a string"` but again probably not important

Comment: Ok, good call on the escape spaces, I went ahead and removed them from any string, but as you mentioned, it was not the problem, still returns the Bad Address error.

Comment: Do you mean that `cmd /c start subl "$filename"` does work, when inside the Git Repo, or that it doesn't work? I don't know how git bash handles the repos on Windows (I'm using Cygwin git and bash and don't have these problems), but it would be interesting to actually see what parameter gets passed to subl, and whether the path in the way it is being passed, exists when searched for by the Windows Explorer. For instance, could short vs. long filename be an issue?

Comment: Interesting. Running the script from windows cmd prompt works with both filename paths pointing in/outside git repositories. So now I'm thinking that isn't the problem. Also I went back to my git bash terminal and ran the script but instead of opening the file with subl, I used vim, and this worked. So there must be something going on with the subl path.